# In Linux, how to ls -l a directory and not the contents of that directory?

Tags: linux, command-line

For example, if I have a directory containing files file1 and file2, and a directory dir1, then "ls -l  file1" will show details just for file1. Doing the same thing for dir1 will instead show the contents of dir1. Is there a way to treat dir1 like file1?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Use `ls -l -d dir` (`-d` will make it stop listing the contents of a directory). From the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Which-files-are-listed.html):

> `-d`, `--directory`
>
> List just the names of directories, as with other types of files, rather
>     than listing their contents. Do not follow symbolic links listed on the
>     command line unless the `--dereference-command-line` (`-H`),
>     `--dereference` (`-L`), or `--dereference-command-line-symlink-to-dir`
>     options are specified.

Comment: Merging single-character parameters also works for ls, so `ls -ld dir` and `ls -dl dir` and `ls -l -d dir` all work equally well.