# How to list directories names but not their contents, in *N*X?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, unix, shell

If I do a simple `ls` specifying a filename pattern, like `ls A*`, for directories that match the pattern, it will enter the directory and give the full listing, but how could I get just the listing for `./` and only the names of the directories inside, but not their contents?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can try this command:

```
ls -d A*/
```

Comment: see also https://superuser.com/a/141989/654930

Answer (score 3):

If you need to do it recursively you could use

```
find . -type d -name A\*
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -l | grep '^d' will list only directories in the '.' current directory
```