# How can I use `ls -d` in SFTP?

Tags: linux, bash, sftp

From [this Question](https://superuser.com/questions/141987/in-linux-how-to-ls-l-a-directory-and-not-the-contents-of-that-directory) I know that I can run `ls -d` to show the directory names only instead of their contents.

**Short question:**

How to do the same with `sftp`.

**Specific problem:**

I have a script which should gather directories:

```
echo ls -1 '*/*/Folder*' | sftp -i /path/to/key user@host
```

If there is more than one folder matching, I receive a list of the folders:

```
path/to/Folder1
path/to/Folder2
[...]
```

If there is only one folder matching, I receive the contents of that folder:

```
path/to/Folder1/File1
path/to/Folder1/File2
[...]
```

But I'd like to see just this:

```
path/to/Folder1
```

---

Note:

- I cannot just use `ssh -c` as I don't have full access.

Comment: You could add `| cut -d / -f 2 | uniq` to your script to only get the uniques.

Comment: I need the full path, so that does not work. But good idea. This works: `| sed -e 's/\/[^\/]*$//' | uniq` because folders will always have a trailing `/` and I have no folders below. It's somehow a dirty workaround though... Any better solution?

Comment: I think everything is going to be a workaround. At least I see nothing in the `ls` included in [sftp](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/sftp.htm) which can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running `ls` in `sftp`, you are not running the system executable `ls`, but a stripped down version included as an internal command of the `sftp` environment. The `-d` option is not supported by this version since it isn't the actual `ls` you are familiar with,and only supports a limited set of options (see `help` in the `sftp` environment):

```
ls [-1afhlnrSt] [path]             Display remote directory listing
```

So, your only choice is to parse the output:

```
echo ls -1 '*/*/Folder*' | sftp -i /path/to/key user@host |
    sed -E 's|(.*/Folder*[^/]*/).*|\1|' | grep -v '^sftp' | sort -u
```

The `sed` will remove anything after the `*/*/Folder*/`, te `grep -v` will remove the line showing the `sftp` prompt and the command run (`sftp> ls -1 */*/Folder*/`) and the `sort -u` will only show unique entries.